# Where did the beheading of the elephant (which later became the head of Lord Ganesha) happen?

Tags: shiva, history, ganesha, shiva-purana

My home town is **[Tiruchirappalli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiruchirappalli)** (i.e Trichy) which is the abbreviated form of *Thirucchiram arutha palli* (Tamil). In English, it literally means '**the place where the holy beheading took place**'.

As I asked all the elders in my city, the reason behind the name, everyone answered the same: "This is the place where the elephant's head was cut off, which was later attached to Lord Ganesha".

Also some people added more details like, "The elephant was lying facing north. So, that's why we should never sleep with our head towards north (There's scientific reason also there behind this. Like direction of Earth's magnetic rays are north-south)" and "The elephant was in the hill (which is the present [Rockfort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiruchirapalli_Rock_Fort) in the city) while it was beheaded. Then a Ganesh temple was built in that place to remember that incident. (Which is now one of the most famous Ganesh temples in India located at the top of [Rockfort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiruchirapalli_Rock_Fort))".

I want to know whether the preceding statements are true. Even though I couldn't find any related stories that reveal where the beheading happened, everything the elders tell absolutely matches with our city's name, temples and places.

Comment: After reading Shiv puran, I have found that it doesn't mentions about the curse of rishi kashyap to lord Shiva, by which Shiva had to behead his own son Ganesha. So which puran describes about it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be somewhere in the Himalayas since Shiva lived on Kailash?